# ADF - Create new instance of a session bean

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I have an application that needs to have multiple instances of a session bean.  I cannot figure out how to create a new bean instance since it reuses the original bean instance everytime.

Comment: What's the use case? There are other scopes that can be useful here - for example `@PageFlowScope`, which is a "per-task-flow" scope. `@SessionScope` has a clear purpose and I think some other one.

Answer (score 1):

here is an idea: Instead of using a bean on session scope, why not using a Map containing the beans, set on session scope?

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many instances are needed , you can register beans  with different names in adfc-config.xml file . Never tried it but you can give it a try . One approach can also be to create an instance of class and put in Session scope by accessing the Session scope from ADFFacesContext .